# How to make a new embed when the first embed reaches the description limit (4096)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have added the logs case for my warn slash command, but I have a problem.. that problem is that if the embed description reaches the limit, i get an error and thats not what I want.

So basically, I want the a new embed to be created as like a "second page", and I can use my pagination function to help with navigating between pages and so on. I just don't exactly know how to do that or how to get started.

I am asking for some assistance here because my goal is to have a functional "warning logs" embed with buttons to navigate through the pages if there are more than one like most users will have.

```
case "logs": {
          const buttonPages = require("../../functions/pagination");
          
          const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
          const userWarnings = await warnSchema.find({ Guild: interaction.guild.id, User: user.id });

          if (!userWarnings?.length) return interaction.reply({ content: `\`${user.tag}\` does not have any warnings.`, ephemeral: true });

          const embedDescription = userWarnings.map((warn) => {
              const moderator = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(warn.Moderator);

              return [
                `<:CL_Shield:937188831227183135> Warn ID: ${warn.id}`,
                `<:CL_ReplyContinued:909444370221137930> Moderator: ${moderator || "unknown"}`,
                `<:CL_ReplyContinued:909444370221137930> User: ${user}`,
                `<:CL_ReplyContinued:909444370221137930> Reason: \`${warn.Reason}\``,
                `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> Date: ${warn.Date}`,
              ].join("\n");
            }).join("\n\n");

          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`${user.tag}'s warnings`)
            .setDescription(embedDescription)
            .setColor("#2f3136");
          
          //const pages = [embed];
          //buttonPages(interaction, pages);
          await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called pagination. Code is below, but here is how it works:

First what you've got to do is determine how many different embeds it'll be. We can do that with description.length/4096, but we need to round up so we'd use Math.ceil. The Array().keys() allows us to get a list of all the numbers up to it to iterate over. For example `Array(3).keys()` would give us `[0, 1, 2]` so we can iterate over it.

We then need to select which part of the description we want to send. We want to start at `(i*4096)` since all previous embeds have 4096 characters, and then we want it to be 4096 characters long so we simply end it at `(i*4096)+4096)`.

You also need to consider that we cannot always use `interaction.reply` as interactions can only be replied to once, so we must use `interaction.channel.send` to send them all to the channel. But, we will want some sort of response to the interaction, so we send the first one as a response to the interaction, and all following ones to the channel.

Here's the code:

```js
for (const i of Array(Math.ceil(embedDescription.length/4096)).keys()) {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(embedDescription.substring((i*4096), (i*4096)+4096))
    if(i === 0) await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    else await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
}
```